# wiimote cpu load

Tags: ros, cpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I am experiencing a weird behavior in wiimote_node. When I launch it and subscribe to the /joy topic, the CPU load of the node goes up to 140%! I run the node in an Intel Core2 Duo, where each processor is 1.8 GHz. It seems that those CPU loads are not justified, but I saw in the code that the publishing rate is 100 Hz. Although I changed that frequency to 10 Hz the node keeps on consuming the same CPU. Does anybody have a clue about it?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9921/wiimote-cpu-load/) by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2011-05-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-06-08**:
I also tested the wiimote node on a Atom-based FitPC2 and noticed it maxed out the CPU completely. Good to see it adressed :)

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-07**:
I see the CPU load and am on it!

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-05-09**:
I'm in china currently, I will look into this problem when I get back and see if I can reproduce this problem. I filed a ticket here for myself: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4948

**Comment by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) on 2011-05-09**:
I measure the CPU usage with top. The usage doesn't change with subscriptions. Even without subscriptions, usage is always around 140%. I did the same test in my laptop (Intel Core i5) with a new diamondback installation and I get a usage of 113%

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-09**:
That seems really weird. How are you measuring the CPU usage of the node (e.g. top)? Does it use the same amount when you aren't subscribed to /joy? What about subscribing to one of the other topics output by the node (/imu for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I checked into trunk a fix that reduced the CPU from 114% to 9%

r37137: https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros-pkg/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=/stacks/joystick_drivers/trunk/wiimote/nodes/wiimote_node.py&view=markup&revision=37137

try it out and tell me how it goes..

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) on 2011-06-09**:
Seems to work well! I didn't see any CPU load bigger than 9% during execution of wiimote_node.py. Thanks!